# Which DB type would be more suitable for high performance purposes?

Tags: c#, database, database-design, nosql, database-engine

I'm looking to design a system that has the following data capabilities:

1. Multiple sources high writing rate, 50K - 100K of records per second (from ).
2. Single source fast reading, single IO fetch operation.

This is basic DB table/set design:

```
  Type name
--------------
Date
Amount
```

- For every new **Type** a new table/set will be created.
- The only fetch operation is `SELECT` by dates (should be clustered primary key or something similar).
- Older than one month tables will be archived.

The offered solutions I've received so far are:

- Pure DB engine such as **Berkeley** or **MS Jet**.
- NoSQL such as **Mongo DB**.

P.S - the system will be written in **C#**.

Comment: 100K records/sec means ~9 billions records/day. Is it what you're after?

Comment: Yes, but this is the top most capacity I'll need, most of the time it will run between 80-40K records per second.

Comment: Has a record to be queryable immediately after being written ? My idea is writing records continuously in memory while another parallel processing persists them using chunks. Your use case looks like a signal acquisition process.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be immediate, even tolerable data loss is acceptable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's still 4 billions records/day, 100 billions records/month. You'll break most database limits (number of rows, or storage), SQL or NoSQL.

Comment: What exactly will you do with the data you read? Specifically, when you read a range of data from the given date, do you need to know every single piece of that data, or you just need to do the SUM (or AVG etc...) on it?

Comment: I'll put the raw information on a graph like so: `SELECT Amount FROM Type1 WHERE Date BETWEEN 1/10/2004 10:00:00 AND 1/10/2004 11:00:00`

Comment: What's the _resolution_ of that graph? Perhaps you don't need to _actually_ store all the data points - maybe you can average-out several data points that are closer than the graph resolution and thus lower this huge INSERT influx?

Comment: The system design requires to save all data points (it has to be very accurate) with some possible data loss, but not averaging or aggregating them.

Comment: @Simon Mourier, look at the first comment here: http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/insert-performance-comparison-of-nosql-vs-sql-servers, also check this out http://www.completedb.com/benchmarks.php.
There are solutions, I just need to find the best one.

Comment: "The system has to to be very accurate with some possible data loss". I am sorry, this does not make sense.

Comment: I meant that the accuracy comes from taking the specific data points without averaging them. Possible data loss will be 1-5 of 500 points.

Comment: @EranBetzalel - First, he's using Oracle, not Jet or Mongo. You didn't mention Oracle nor SQL Server. Plus I didn't say you couldn't insert 100K rows per seconds with these databases. I said you'll have hard time *storing* this during a month.

Comment: A day is 86400 seconds. You probably dont want to *store* 50K to 100K of a record that represent a date/amount pair. Is your date storage *that* precise ? How about storing a Date/Amount/Count instead, with a datetime precision up to the second ?

Comment: 50-100K is an approximation for the sum of all **Types**, each type will have between 1-100 amounts per second. The date time will be accurate to the millisecond.

Comment: I've just tested Berkeley DB and managed to insert 200K records per second :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redis** would be the perfect solution, but the requirements are much simpler than that and it appears that **Berkeley DB** would suit just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/) and [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) for C#.

Here is a link for  [Comparison of NoSQL DB's](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis).

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why should I choose NoSQL over DB engine such as Berkeley?

Comment: I don't need to keep all the information "alive", I only need one month/one week of information to query from, while the rest of the data would be archived.

Berkeley might be more suitable for me, no?

Comment: Berkeley is a local database engine. Are the "multiple source high writing rate" you mention on the same machine or distributed across the network ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you do is write from many writers and read once sequentially, you don't need a database but rather a queue system. ZeroMQ is extremely fast.

Comment: The reading will be performed by a monitor/view system. The user will choose a type and date range to fetch the data by. It won't be a one time operation.

Comment: P.S - give my regards to Ami ;-)